# flask-restx how to convert a model to an example

Tags: flask-restx

I use flask-restx 0.5.1 to define my API.
When describing payload parameter with

```
@ns.expect(mymodel, description="my model parameter description")
```

I get the following
[image]

When I additionally use

```
@ns.param('payload', description="This is my payload description but without auto-generated example", example={"key": "value"})
```

I can get the following

[image]

As it is very convenient and nice to see the generated example as in the first picture, I wonder how can I get both, my payload description **AND** the example?
Thx

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

You have to use

```
@ns.param('payload', 'some description goes here', _in='body)
```

The missing piece was the **_in="body"**